# oracledb TypeError: Schema is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, database-schema, node-oracledb

I've encountered an error in a model while deploying it on the console, I get this prompt

```
TypeError: Schema is not a constructor
```

Im very new at Javascript, so I don't understand what's wrong. Based on the promts in the log I get that error at 2 archives in model -and the other in my route.

Here's the code on my model

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb')
const Schema = oracledb.Schema

const Meals = oracledb.model('Meal', new Schema({ //I get the error at this line on new Schema
name: String, 
desc: String, 
}))

module.exports = Meals
```

Code on my Route

```
const express = require ('express')
const Meals = require ('../models/Meals') //I get the error also here

const router = express.Router()

router.get('/', (req, res) =>{
Meals.find()
.exec()
.then(x => res.status(200).send(x))
})

router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
Meals.findById(req.params.id)
.exec()
.then(x => res.status(200).send(x))
})

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
Meals.create(req.body).then(x => res.status(201).send(x))
})

router.put('/:id', (req, res) => {
Meals.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body)
.then(() => res.sendStatus(204))
})

router.delete('/:id', (req, res) => {
Meals.findOneAndDelete(req.params.id).exec().then(() => res.sendStatus(204))
})
module.exports = router
```

So.. what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you try to instantiate an object of the Schema type and it is not successful, because you try calling a constructor which does not exist. Let me break it down to you, concept by concept

## Classes

Classes are general definitions of objects of their particular type. A class is a general set, which can be instantiated into objects. This is a basic OOP concept, so I recommend reading about OOP (Object Oriented Programming) as well.

So, if your object is a man, then your class represents everyone. This is the relation between classes and objects.

I should also mention that you can instantiate a function as well into objects, but, in order to avoid confusing you, I will not delve into this at this point.

## Instances

An instance is an object instantiated based on a class. It can be instantiated via a constructor call, like

```
let myInstance = new MyClass();
```

where `MyClass` is the class you instantiate and `myInstance` is the resulting object/instance.

## Your problem

```
const Meals = oracledb.model('Meal', new Schema({ //I get the error at this line on new Schema
name: String, 
desc: String, 
}))
```

this code attempts to instantiate Schema and pass the resulting object as the second parameter of your call of `oracledb.model`. You will need to look into `Schema`. You already created such an object via

```
const Schema = oracledb.Schema
```

so, you will need to take a look into how `Schema` can be instantiated and change your code accordingly.